# How to use AjaxToolKit Confirm Button Extender?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my ASP.NET web-based application, I have a normal ASP.NET button that has a method behind it for sending emails as following:

**ASP.NET Code:**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSendReminders" runat="server" Text="Send Reminders" OnClick="btnSendReminders_Click"  />
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
protected void btnSendReminders_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendEmailTOAllUser();
        }


        protected void SendEmail(string toAddresses, string fromAddress, string MailSubject, string MessageBody, bool isBodyHtml)
        {
            SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("Mail Server");
            try
            {
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                msg.From = new MailAddress("pssp@aramco.com", "PMOD Safety Services Portal (PSSP)");

                // In case the mail system doesn't like no to recipients. This could be removed
                //msg.To.Add("psTeesstp@DomainServer.com");

                msg.Bcc.Add(toAddresses);
                msg.Subject = MailSubject;
                msg.Body = MessageBody;
                msg.IsBodyHtml = isBodyHtml;
                sc.Send(msg);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }

        protected void SendEmailTOAllUser()
        {
            string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspForTest;Integrated Security=True";

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                var sbEmailAddresses = new System.Text.StringBuilder(2000);
                string quizid = "";

                // Open DB connection.
                conn.Open();

                string cmdText = "SELECT MAX (QuizID) As mQuizID FROM dbo.QUIZ WHERE IsSent <> 0";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
                {
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader != null)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            // There is only 1 column, so just retrieve it using the ordinal position
                            quizid = reader["mQuizID"].ToString();

                        }
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }

                string cmdText2 = @"SELECT e.Username, d.DivisionShortcut
                                FROM
                                  employee e
                                  join Divisions d on (e.DivisionCode = d.SapCode)
                                  left join 
                                    (select A.QuizID, a.Username 
                                     from UserQuiz a join 
                                     (select max(QuizID) QuizID from dbo.Quiz where IsSent=1) b
                                     on a.QuizId = b.QuizID
                                     ) c
                                   on e.Username = c.Username
                                 WHERE c.QuizID is null
                                 Order By d.DivisionShortcut";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText2, conn))
                {
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader != null)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            var sName = reader.GetString(0);
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sName))
                            {
                                if (sbEmailAddresses.Length != 0)
                                {
                                    sbEmailAddresses.Append(",");
                                }
                                // Just use the ordinal position for the user name since there is only 1 column
                                sbEmailAddresses.Append(sName).Append("@DomainServer.com");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    reader.Close();


                    // Add the parameter to the command
                    var oParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@QuizID", SqlDbType.Int);


                    var sEMailAddresses = sbEmailAddresses.ToString();
                    string link = "<a href='http://StartQuiz.aspx?testid=" + quizid + "'> Click here to participate </a>";
                    string body = @"<font color='red' size='18pt'><b> ***REMINDER*** </b></font> <br /><br /> 
                                Good day, <br /><br />
                                <b>This is just a gentle reminder asking you to participate in the last new short safety quiz </b>"
                                    + link +
                                    @"<br /><br />
                                Also, give yourself a chance to gain more safety culture by reading the PMOD Newsletter.
                                <br /><br /><br />
                                PLEASE <span class='highlight'>IGNORE</span> THIS MESSAGE IF YOU HAVE ALREADY PARTICIPATED IN THIS QUIZ.
                                <br /> <br /><br /> <br />
                                This email was generated using the <a href='http://pmv/pssp/Default.aspx'>Safety Portal (PSSP) </a>. 
                                Please do not reply to this email.";

                    int sendCount = 0;
                    List<string> addressList = new List<string>(sEMailAddresses.Split(','));
                    StringBuilder addressesToSend = new StringBuilder();

                    for (int userIndex = 0; userIndex < addressList.Count; userIndex++)
                    {
                        sendCount++;
                        if (addressesToSend.Length > 0)
                            addressesToSend.Append(",");

                        addressesToSend.Append(addressList[userIndex]);
                        if (sendCount == 10 || userIndex == addressList.Count - 1)
                        {
                            SendEmail(addressesToSend.ToString(), "", "REMINDER: Notification of New Weekly Safety Quiz", body, true);
                            addressesToSend.Clear();
                            sendCount = 0;
                        }
                    }


                    // Update the parameter for the current quiz
                    oParameter.Value = quizid;
                    // And execute the command
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Now, instead of using `<asp:Button>`, I want to use:

```
 <ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="btnSendReminders" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnSendReminders"
                                                ConfirmText="Are you sure you want to click this?"
                                                OnClientCancel="CancelClick" />
```

to have a ConfirmMessage. But I don't know why I got the following error:
**

> Extender control 'btnSendReminders' cannot extend 'btnSendReminders'.
>   Extender controls of type 'AjaxControlToolkit.ConfirmButtonExtender'
>   cannot extend controls of type
>   'AjaxControlToolkit.ConfirmButtonExtender'.

And I don't know why. So how can I use it instead of the `<asp:button>`?

**UPDATE:**

I just figured out how to use it. I should use it as following:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSendReminders" runat="server" Text="Send Reminders" OnClick="btnSendReminders_Click"  />
            <ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="ConfirmButtonExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnSendReminders"
                                                ConfirmText="Are you sure you want to send reminders to these employees?"
                                                OnClientCancel="CancelClick">
                                                </ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender>
```

But the problem now is when the confirm message appears, and click on the Cancel button, still the page will be refreshed and the reminders will be sent. **How to prevent that in case of clicking the Cancel button?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code Confirm button ajax extender to get confirm box:

```
  <asp:Button ID="btnSendReminders" runat="server" Text="Send Reminders" OnClick="btnSendReminders_Click"  />
<ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="cbe" runat="server"
   TargetControlID="btnSendReminders"
    ConfirmText="Are you sure you want to Send Reminders?"
    />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use clientside return confirm to do the same

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSendReminders" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to proceed?')" runat="server" Text="Send Reminders" OnClick="btnSendReminders_Click"  />
```